# How to change color of DistanceTransform image?

Tags: image-processing, distance

I want to overlay a set of points onto a distance transform of them. But, I don't really like the black default color of the distance transform. Is there a way to change this?

Given the points `pts`:

```
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 2}];
```

We can compute their distance transform image (+ `ImageAdjust`):

```
Dpts = DistanceTransform[Graphics[Point[pts]]] // ImageAdjust;
```

Then, compose this image with the points (say, red points):

```
ImageCompose[Dpts, Graphics[{RGBColor[0.82, 0., 0.34], Point[pts]}]]
```

To obtain a nice overlay, but it's not pretty (it's, well, too "dark"):

[image: distance transform]

Can we change the color appearance of the distance transform?

Additionally, can we adjust the image resolution? Zooming in just makes evident that the image is not very high-res.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, I really recommend image processing docs - lots useful stuff there:

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ImageProcessing.html
- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ColorProcessing.html

`DistanceTransform` resolution depends on your original image resolution which you can control in `Graphics`:

```
dpts = ImageAdjust[DistanceTransform[Graphics[Point[pts], ImageSize -> 500]]]
```

There are many ways to change color schemes. For instance:

```
Colorize[dpts, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
ImageCompose[%,Graphics[{RGBColor[0.82,0.,0.34],Point[pts]}]]
```

[image]

Available color schemes are listed here:

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ColorSchemes.html

Another method would be changing colors based on another image

```
i = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Apples"}]
```

[image]

color distribution making use of `HistogramTransform`:

```
HistogramTransform[ColorConvert[dpts,"RGB"],i];
ImageCompose[%,Graphics[{RGBColor[0.82,0.,0.34],Point[pts]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As Vitaliy notes, `Colorize[]` is the key. Here, I'll demonstrate a slightly different way of putting in the markers:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42]; (* for reproducibility *)
            pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 2}];]

npts = Rasterize[Graphics[{PointSize[Small], Point[pts]}], "Image",
                 ImageResolution -> 300];

dpts = Colorize[ImageAdjust[DistanceTransform[npts]], ColorFunction -> "LakeColors"];

npts = Colorize[npts, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{RGBColor[0.82, 0., 0.34, 1],
                                               Transparent}, #] &)];

ImageCompose[dpts, npts]
```

[image: DistanceTransform + markers]